# Strange warning behavior with gcc and signed/unsigned comparisons

Tags: c++, comparison, compiler-warnings

I have the following code :

```
unsigned int a;
if (a > numeric_limits<int>::max())
   do_stuff();
```

When compiling, gcc complains about

> warning: "comparison between signed and unsigned"

OK, I understand

But, with the following code :

```
unsigned int a;
if (a > (numeric_limits<int>::max()))
   do_stuff();
```

The warning is no longer displayed and I really don't know why...
Is there any logical reason for such a behavior or am I doing something wrong?!

Comment: Tried to [simulate this behavior](http://www.ideone.com/5NZL9). But it shows warning.

Comment: What is the surrounding code?

Comment: The do_stuff() part only consists in throwing an exception. There is no surrounding code as this is the only lines within a function. However, the function is used in a large project. I tried the code provided by iammilind but the warning doesn't appear. Here are the gcc options I use to compile the program `-Wall -ansi -pedantic -Wno-long-long`

Comment: @malamioute Create a *complete* (= compiling), *minimal* example that still exhibits this behaviour (well, *two* examples, one with the warning and one without) and post those. Since we cannot reproduce your problem, this suggests that the issue is actually elsewhere.

Comment: I can see this happening on gcc 4.6 too. maybe a bug, maybe introduced to be able to silent that warning without a cast? Probably best thing to do is to ask the gcc guys directly. (can see this also on 4.5 and 4.7)

Comment: @KonradRudolph I've tested this behavior with the minimal code (compiling) provided by iammilind (see [link](http://www.ideone.com/5NZL9)). The warning does not appear in that case. The gcc version I use is 4.6

Comment: I see it with gcc 4.5.3.

Answer (score 5):

It's because it is a bug. See [bug 50012](http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=50012)

Answer (score 0):

I do not currently have access to a C++ compiler to test this, but I think this might work without any warnings:

```
unsigned int a;
if (a > numeric_limits<unsigned int>::max())
   do_stuff();
```

Comment: This should definitely produce a warning (statement always false)!

Comment: To get the same result without a warning would take `if (a > unsigned(numeric_limits<int>::max()))`.

Comment: I see it now too. `a` cannot be greater than `0xffffffff`, so `if (a > unsigned(numeric_limits<int>::max()))` is correct, as @UncleBens indicated.

Answer (score -1):

The answer lies in the way gcc handles `int` and `unsigned int`.

`unsigned int` and `int` both store a 2 byte value. The difference between them is that `unsigned int` does not support negative values. It can only store values from 0-65,535. 
When GCC sees a comparison between int and unsigned int it converts the int to a positive number. e.g if the value of the `int` is -2 it will convert it to 2. But if the int is preceded by the () operator . (int). GCC interprets it as a positive number (but still converts it) and doesn't give a warning.

Comment: `int` is not a "2 byte value" in general, and not on pretty much any C++ compiler actually used today.